# Trouble sorting table elements in a case statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

Im trying to create a switch statement to sort different elements of a table, in numerical and alphabetical order depending on what the user chooses. However when I try to reference the field questions.id for the sort function, it says it is undefined? Additionally, if I do not define anything and try to sort by the the first field (ID) it numbers 126 ahead of 1? Here is the code I have so far:

```js
$('#sort').on('click', sort);

function sort(){

  //Clear all existing rows, so that additional queries do not pile up on top
  $("#questions tbody tr").remove(); 

  //Get the JSON data from our HTML and convert it to a JavaScript object
  //In the real world, this data will likely be retrieved  from the server via an AJAX request
  var questions = [
    {
      "id":1,
      "q_category_id":0,
      "q_text":"Which of the following is regarded as the real founder of portugese power in India",
      "q_options_1":"Pedro Cabral",
      "q_options_2":"Almeida",
      "q_options_3":"Vasco da Gama",
      "q_options_4":"Alfonso de Albuquerque",
      "q_correct_option":4,
      "q_difficulty_level":2,
      "q_date_added":"2013-06-10T04:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ];

  var sortquery = $('#sortquestions').val();

  switch (sortquery){
    case 'Ascending ID':
      console.log(sortquery);
      questions.id.sort()
      break;

    case 'Descending ID':
      console.log(sortquery);
      break;

    case 'Ascending Alphabetical':
      console.log(sortquery);
      questions.q_text.sort();
      break;

    case 'Descending Alphabetical':
      console.log(sortquery);
      break;

    case 'Ascending Difficulty':
      console.log(sortquery);
      break;

    case 'Descending Difficulty':
      console.log(sortquery);
      break;
  }

  //Loop through the list array and create a table row for each item.
  $.each(questions, function(i, question) {
    var tblRow = '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + question.id + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_text + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_options_1 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_options_2 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_options_3 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_options_4 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_correct_option + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_difficulty_level + '</td>' +
        '</tr>'
    //Add our table row to the 'questions' <table>
    $(tblRow).appendTo('#questions tbody');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="sort" value="sort" />
<select id="sortquestions">
  <option>Ascending ID</option>
  <option>Descending ID</option>
  <option>Ascending Alphabetical</option>
  <option>Descending Alphabetical</option>
  <option>Ascending Difficulty</option>
  <option>Descending Difficulty</option>
</select>
<table id="questions">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, have clarified it, also missed an edit in the code.

Comment: Can we also see what is in the contents of the `questions` object?

Comment: Added an example of an object from questions.

Comment: will need to use custom sort function to sort numerically. There is not enough code shown to help resolve your issues. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net or other sandbox that replicates problem

Comment: Im not quite sure how to get it to work in jsfiddle, but I tried adding a comparefunction to the sort: questions.sort(function(a,b) { return b - a; }); although even if I swapped b-a to a-b it did not change the way things were sorted, not sure why that is either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about how the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function works. I've implemented a custom sort for you in the example below.

```js
$('#sort').on('click', sort);

function sort(){

  //Clear all existing rows, so that additional queries do not pile up on top
  $("#questions tbody tr").remove(); 

  //Get the JSON data from our HTML and convert it to a JavaScript object
  //In the real world, this data will likely be retrieved  from the server via an AJAX request
  var questions = [
    {
      "id":1,
      "q_category_id":0,
      "q_text":"Which of the following is regarded as the real founder of portugese power in India",
      "q_options_1":"Pedro Cabral",
      "q_options_2":"Almeida",
      "q_options_3":"Vasco da Gama",
      "q_options_4":"Alfonso de Albuquerque",
      "q_correct_option":4,
      "q_difficulty_level":2,
      "q_date_added":"2013-06-10T04:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "q_category_id":0,
      "q_text":"Another question",
      "q_options_1":"A",
      "q_options_2":"B",
      "q_options_3":"C",
      "q_options_4":"D",
      "q_correct_option":4,
      "q_difficulty_level":1,
      "q_date_added":"2014-06-10T04:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ];

  var sortquery = $('#sortquestions').val();
  
  //custom sort based on the selected item in the dropdown
  questions.sort(function(a, b) {
    switch (sortquery){
      case 'Ascending ID':
        return a.id > b.id;
      case 'Descending ID':
        return b.id > a.id;
      case 'Ascending Alphabetical':
        return a.q_text > b.q_text;
      case 'Descending Alphabetical':
        return b.q_text > a.q_text;
      case 'Ascending Difficulty':
        return a.q_difficulty_level > b.q_difficulty_level;
      case 'Descending Difficulty':
        return b.q_difficulty_level > a.q_difficulty_level;
    }
  });

  //Loop through the list array and create a table row for each item.
  $.each(questions, function(i, question) {
    var tblRow = '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + question.id + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_text + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_options_1 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_options_2 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_options_3 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_options_4 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_correct_option + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + question.q_difficulty_level + '</td>' +
        '</tr>'
    //Add our table row to the 'questions' <table>
    $(tblRow).appendTo('#questions tbody');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="sort" value="sort" />
<select id="sortquestions">
  <option>Ascending ID</option>
  <option>Descending ID</option>
  <option>Ascending Alphabetical</option>
  <option>Descending Alphabetical</option>
  <option>Ascending Difficulty</option>
  <option>Descending Difficulty</option>
</select>
<table id="questions">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```